# Simple scroll element with jQuery Mobile or use something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, iscroll4

I really want to use jQuery mobile, but my first needs are just to control what areas are scrollable and create fixed menus, etc.

This takes lots of effort with that toolset, when it's VERY easy with something like iScroll http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Is there an **easy** way to accomplish a scrollable area or fixed position elements with jQuery mobile?

Comment: iScroll also has problem with form elements

Comment: My question was if jQuery mobile can create scrollable areas simply.

Comment: This question has also been answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763619/jquery-mobile-fixed-toolbar-and-footer-bar-disappears/5914035#5914035.

Comment: Also, wink is another toolkit which allows for scrolling.  However, I wasn't able to easily get it working with my particular7 jquery mobile project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile is way too much setup just to create scrollable areas.

iScroll would be what you need. And unlike jQuery mobile, iScroll works on various devices and on the desktop. jQuery mobile, not so much.

And to the person who said that is has a *problem with form elements*, he is right, but there is an easy fix...
[iScroll 4 not working with form <select> element iPhone Safari and Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745374/iscroll-4-problem-with-form-select-element-iphone-safari-and-android-browser).

Comment: Yah it works but things like transition and animations do not animate properly on many Android devices. Parts of the framework are also borked on the desktop as well.