# JQuery Mobile fixed footer inside form

Tags: jquery, mobile, fixed

I'm trying to put a submit button of a form on a fixed footer. Problem is that when footer with data-position="fixed" is placed inside a form then it's not fixed. If i move the footer outside of the form, it becomes fixed but the submit button does not work.

Is there any way to put form buttons on a fixed footer in JQuery Mobile (1.0rc3)?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this existing question:-


**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377062/how-to-fix-jquery-mobiles-fixed-footer**

Comment: I tried iscroll demo on my blackberry 9360 and it does not work. i guess JQuery mobile is not fully compatible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this URL for some more information:-

> http://yappo.github.com/projects/jquery.mobile.iscroll/livedemo.html
>
> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/58
>
> [How to fix jQuery Mobile's fixed footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377062/how-to-fix-jquery-mobiles-fixed-footer)

Refer this answer too:-

[JQuery Mobile Fixed Toolbar and Footer Bar disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763619/jquery-mobile-fixed-toolbar-and-footer-bar-disappears/5763753#5763753)

Comment: tnx for the links. most of it points to iscroll which also seems to malfunction on blackberry 9360