# jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 any page onClick hides fixed footer

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

After fixing a footer in jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, any time i click anywhere on the page the page footer slides down. Upon inspection I found that the ui-fixed-hidden class was being applied to the footer, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile Fixed Toolbar and Footer Bar disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763619/jquery-mobile-fixed-toolbar-and-footer-bar-disappears)

Answer (score 19):

Adding the following anywhere data-position="fixed" occurs fixes the problem

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0 final release, which means I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

I added data-tap-toggle="false" as recommended here (and in many other questions here on stackoverflow), but that did not solve my issue with the header.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

So, I also added the following, and this fixes my issue.

```
.ui-header.ui-fixed-hidden {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```