# How to make pull to refresh in phonegap without using jquery mobile

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, pull-to-refresh

I am making pull to refresh listview in phonegap Project. But i also do no want to use jquery mobile. Please suggest me how i can achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). It supports pull-to-refresh dynamic loading of content and is not dependent on jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I used it but it makes disable all clicks on screen.

Comment: Make sure the clickable elements have a higher z-index than the iScroll scroller, e.g. `.iscroll-scroller{ z-index: 1;} .clickable-stuff{ z-index: 2;}` Also have a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345644/iscroll-wont-let-items-be-clicked)