# Selection option in PhoneGap not working proper

Tags: android, cordova

I developed an application in the phonegap which is working good in the android 3.2 and above versions. when i run the same application in 2.3 or lesser then 3.2 all the app is working fine rest to the select option, select option (spinner)  is not working properly,

I saw that it could come from the CSS: -webkit-backface-visibility 
which is hidden in the jqtouch.css

After change this properties, the options still does not appear.

Do you have an idea to open the options of the select field on 
Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this [iScroll 4 not working with form <select> element iPhone Safari and Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745374/iscroll-4-problem-with-form-select-element-iphone-safari-and-android-browser)

i was facing the same issue. worked for me. just a small change. instead of doing for select tag, do for all the tags for which u face the issue.