# combo box not working after load/use iscroll in page

Tags: combobox, iscroll4

I am using iscroll4 in my application. I am facing problem with iScroll that made drop down lists(combo box) unusable when used at the same time.
I tried how they mentioned here
( http://groups.google.com/group/iscroll/browse_thread/thread/5b2fbad6aa667907# )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var destinations_scroll, accounts_scroll;
    function loadingIscroll() {
        accounts_scroll = new iScroll('accounts_container');
        destinations_scroll = new iScroll('destinations_container', {
            checkDOMChanges: true
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            destinations_scroll.refresh();
        }, 0);
    }
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        if (e.target.tagName != "SELECT") {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, false);
    addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadingIscroll, false);

});
```

But still select box (combo box/drop down) not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got an answer from [iScroll 4 not working with form <select> element iPhone Safari and Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745374/iscroll-4-problem-with-form-select-element-iphone-safari-and-android-browser). Thanks to @comonitos. I used his solution.