# iScroll 4 not scrolling on input elements

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iscroll

I'm building a mobile app that targets Android 2.2+, Blackberry 9+ and iOS 4+. In our stack we  are using Phonegap, jQuery and [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) (amongst others).

One of our app screens looks like this (text redacted for anonymity) - running in the iOS 5 simulator's Safari.

[image: App Screenshot]

As you can see, this is a typical input screen with a fixed header, and multiple block-level form elements stretching the full with of the device screen, less padding.

As I mentioned, our app uses iScroll. We're initialising it on this page using the following code (taken from the iScroll 'forms' sample).

```
// ...

window.scroller = new iScroll(id, {
    useTransform: false,
    onBeforeScrollStart: function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
        if(target.tagName != 'select'
            && target.tagName != 'input'
            && target.tagName != 'textarea') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

// Disable touch scrolling (Req'd for iScroll)
window.document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// ...
```

On this screen, I've noticed that the content scrolls fine when the user touches any part of the background, but doesn't scroll when you begin the scroll gesture (swiping up or down) by touching one of the input elements. As you can understand this essentially makes this screen impossible to use, hence me looking for a fix.

I've since found the culprit line in iScroll;

```
if (nodeName == "TEXTAREA" || nodeName == "INPUT" || nodeName == "SELECT" ) return;
```

(179 in iscroll.js), an [open issue for this bug](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/276) with a claimed fix, and one [pull request that claims to fix it](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/pull/190), however the author of the bug seems to have incorrect line numbers, preventing me from attempting that fix, and the mentioned pull request doesn't work for me (tested on iOS 5.1, Android 4.0.4).

My question - is there some way to allow a user to scroll (using iScroll) when touching an input element? If not, iScroll is completely useless in cases like this. At the moment, I'm looking at either

- Using the [Overthrow shim](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/) that claims to have identical functionality to iScroll - however this isn't a great option due to [various](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/issues/2) [issues](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/issues/20) [with](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/issues/1) [Android](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/issues/20) - one of our key platforms.
- Doing away with iScroll and loosing my fixed header.

It's 2012 - do we still not have a way to do this on Mobile browsers?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and used the following when I set up my iScroll:

```
var ISCROLL_MOVE;

var ISCROLL_MOVE_LIMIT=10;

// ... functions to include when you set up your iScroll
onScrollStart: function(e) {
                ISCROLL_MOVE=0;
            },
            onScrollMove: function(e) {
                ISCROLL_MOVE_LIMIT++;
            }
```

Then when you have any form elements in your iScroll, e.g.:

```
var selectField = document.getElementById('mySelectField');

selectField.addEventListener('touchend' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {

        if (SCROLL_MOVE<SCROLL_MOVE_LIMIT)
            this.focus();

    }, false);
```

Note the action is on a touch end event, and it allows for scrolling iScroll pages when the user touches on a form element - basically it measures the amount of scrolling ( or not ) which the user is making ( the amount of SCROLL_MOVE ). If its more than 10 ( the SCROLL_MOVE_LIMIT seems like a good number to me ) then the field won't grab focus , otherwise it will.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Hmmm - sad that we need a hack to get this working. Thanks for your answer regardless!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this ticket is a bit old but I ran into it while dealing with the same issue.
I am using iScroll v4 on iOS.

I found this solution (somewhere) to add the following when setting up the iScroll object:

```
        myScroll = new iScroll(id, {
            useTransform: false,
            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                var target = e.target;
                while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

                if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

However I found 2 issues with this code:

a) The useTransform broke layout for a form where I was auto hiding radio buttons in order to show "pretty graphic" ones as per this page (http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).  I don't know why this would break that layout and possibly it was only a partial relationship I could have fixed another way but...I commented out the useTransform and it fixed it so...

b) For inputs that pulled up the virtual keyboard, the page stayed "scrolled up" (header off screen and footer about 1/4 up from bottom ) after the keyboard was hidden, so I added and "onBlur" event to "rescroll" the window and that seemed to work so... here is my final solution.

```
    myScroll = new iScroll(id, {
        //useTransform: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                $(target).bind('blur', function(){
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    myScroll.refresh();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the preventDefault():

```
window.scroller = new iScroll(id, {
    useTransform: false,
    onBeforeScrollStart: function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
        if(target.tagName != 'select'
            && target.tagName != 'input'
            && target.tagName != 'textarea') {

            // remove this code right here:
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ps:even works with the iscroll without the fix!i do not understand it at all, anyway ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i'd answer about it here, without java-script and iscroll hacks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390516/1458628

Answer (score 0):

I solved it perfectly. If you are using iscroll.js, then you can solve it easily by editing the iscroll.js file.

I edited the _move(e) function definition.
You will see the below code in the function definition of _move(e):
    enter code here

```
that.moved = true;
   that._pos(newX, newY);
   that.dirX = deltaX > 0 ? -1 : deltaX < 0 ? 1 : 0;
that.dirY = deltaY > 0 ? -1 : deltaY < 0 ? 1 : 0;
if (timestamp - that.startTime > 300) {
   that.startTime = timestamp;
   that.startX = that.x;
   that.startY = that.y;
}
if (that.options.onScrollMove) that.options.onScrollMove.call(that, e);
```

//Enclose the above code in the else condition. And the if condition should be below:

```
enter code here
if (e.srcElement.localName == 'textarea') {
  var scrollHeight = e.srcElement.scrollHeight;
  var scrollTop = e.srcElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= 0 && screenTop <= scrollHeight) {
       that.dirY = that.dirY * 5;
       e.srcElement.scrollTop = scrollTop + that.dirY;
  }
}
```

//Tested in IPad. Works fine for me.